# HAProxy, Varnish and Multiple websites with SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, haproxy, varnish

I can't seem to find any documentation on setting this kind of configuration up with Apache. I have 1 load balancer and 2 slaves running MySQL replication and unison syncing both machines and website totally. There is a number of non SSL sites being hosted on these boxes but I want to add support for varnish and SSL termination on the load balancer, is this even possible to do for multiple sites on this kind of setup.

I had issues before trying to run multiple SSL certs just on a standard Debian server before so I'm a bit worried that this can't be configured. Most of the documentation available on similar setups is geared towards NGINX but I will be stinking with apache for the moment.

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com/questions/297880/architecture-question-adding-ssl-into-the-mix

Comment: I feel like [this](http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/08/25/haproxy-varnish-and-the-single-hostname-website/) is relevant. You'd need to modify things a little to get it working for multiple websites and your static content locations, but it's still a good read.